# Formatting a Y2K date value in Databricks

Tags: databricks, y2k

The date of Jan 01, 1901 converts to Jan 01, 2001 which is wrong.  How is this done in Databricks?

```
%sql
Select '01-Jan-01' badDate, to_date('01-Jan-01','dd-MMM-yy') as date2, date_format('01-Jan-01','d-MMM-yy'),,date_format('01-Jan-01','dd-MM-yy'),date_format('01-01-01','dd-MM-yy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what you're asking but your date format string is incorrectly formated for one. You have dd-MMM-yy when it should be dd-MM-yy

Comment: Can you show an example?   I think the MMM indicates we are using the month abbreviation rather than an actual numeric value for the month.  Perhaps I should add the CSV file has the date written as '01-Jan-01' and the date needs to be converted to something like '1901-01-01' or more simply - it needs to be interpreted as a date and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - since it is Databricks.  Use a Python function to convert it using a cutoff date of '01-01-'+ year(date)

```
cutoff_date = pd.to_datetime('01-01-2023')
df.loc[df.date > cutoff_date, 'date'] -= pd.DateOffset(years=100)
```

Possible solution  [Easy way to fix wrong year (y2k bug) using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168678/easy-way-to-fix-wrong-year-y2k-bug-using-pandas)

Comment: That could work if the cutoff date could list as '01-01-2000', the Y2K date, but it isn't functional unless there can be certainty that the date will always be from the 20th century and that is not an option.